# What does =slug= means in the context of =org-roam=?

Tags: bibtex, org-roam

I'm trying of configuring `org-roam-bibtex` (not there yet), but I keep finding this `${slug}` function, which I don't understand. See for example [This post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/59126/how-to-configure-org-roam-bibtex-properly).

What is it? What is its utility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be other uses that I'm not aware of, but slug is the text passed into the template system from your search.

Answer (score 4):

The *slug* is used to construct the filename. By default org-roam uses the title of the note, using the `org-roam--title-to-slug` function. A note titled =This is my note title!!= will be turned into the slug `"this_is_my_note_title"`, which has no spaces or exclamation marks in the filename. (I prefer dashes myself)

In the post you link to, you can see how it constructs the filename by combining the slug with the timestamp `:file-name "literature/%<%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S>-${slug}"`

I hadn't seen the word *slug* used for this before but Wikipedia says [it's the part of the URL that has human readable keywords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL#Slug).